# Responsive issue with iDangerous swiper

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, swiper.js

I'm having an issue with a iDangerous responsive swiper in IE 9/10.

The last slide is dropping down underneath the first slide as (I think) the width of the element containing all the slides is being calculated incorrectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/Msffg/

I'm calling a simple swiper function:

```
$this.swiper({
    calculateHeight: true,
    mode: 'horizontal',
    resistance: '100%',
    simulateTouch: false,
    speed: 500
});
```

And calling resizeFix() on $(window).on('resize');

The problem only occurs at certain window sizes so a quick resize of the viewport should reveal the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.  The last slide is sometimes dropped underneath the first on IE.

I'm pretty sure it was a rounding problem on IE's part, because I fixed it by setting the following when initialising swiper:

```
roundLengths: true
```